# Disposing a .NET Crystal ReportDocument

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have a factory class that keeps an instance of a `CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument`. I'm implementing IDisposable per [an awesome SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface), but not sure if the resource is managed or unmanaged.

I'm assuming it's managed since a .NET library, and doing it like this:

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

public class ReportFactory: IDisposable {

    public ReportDocument Report { get; private set; }
    private bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool freeManagedReousrces) {
        try {
            if (IsDisposed) return;
            if ((freeManagedReousrces)) {
                // Release managed resources.
                if (Report != null) {
                    Report.Dispose();
                }
            }
            // Release un-managed resources.
            // None
        }
        finally {
            IsDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    // No finalizer needed: no unmanaged resources.
}
```

Please verify that the ReportDocument is a managed resource and that I'm handling it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. It gave me the [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) badge for inactivity, so I did more digging and concluded from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786570/determine-managed-vs-unmanaged-resources) that if an object implements IDisposable it is a managed resource, and I am disposing it properly.